# How can I make a 3x3 matrix from a list of integers?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, matrix, printing

So I am currently working through some code and I have run into a problem I can't find a way without using built-ins and map function to make a 3x3 matrix using the `lst` I have generated.

```
    string = input('Please enter the numbers 1 through 9 in the order you want them in the square: ')
    lst = []
    for char in string:
        if char != ' ' and char.isdigit() == True:
            lst.append(int(char))
            
    while len(lst) != 9:
        string = input('Please enter the numbers 1 through 9 in the order you want them in the square: ')
        lst = []
        for char in string:
            if char != ' ' and char.isdigit() == True:
                lst.append(int(char))
```

lets say my `string = 123 4 5 6 7 8 9`

that means `lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

**I want my program to print:**

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Using the values from the `lst`

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension as follows.

```
[lst[3 * i: 3 * (i+1)] for i in range(3)]
```